# Angular jqLite on $destroy not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

I have a div called MyDiv and am bootstraping Angular manually to it (due to some limitations from a legacy system).  In a particular case, I would like that on $destroy I do some further processing.  I am using the below snippet, however it seems that it doesn't trigger anything  - the console logging is not working :(

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#MyDiv')).on('$destroy', function() { 
     // do something
     console.log("test");
});
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  This is the first time I am relying on jqLite as usually I use the full jQuery.  I am using this in a controller not a directive.

Additional Detail:

I've also tried using the below, however I get this error in the console: Error: [jqLite:nosel] Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!.  This used to work when I was loading AngularJS after jQuery but i had to change the order to load angular first, and therefore have to rely on jqLite.

```
angular.element('#MyDiv').on('$destroy', function() {
        alert("Test");
    });
```

*Note* - if there is a way to do this using native js that is fine.

Thanks

Comment: @Aravind that post is about possible uses of $destroy in jqLite.  This is a case when im trying to use it but it's not being triggered and thus the "// do something"  (even when i try to console or alerting) doesn't work out :/

Comment: As far as I know `$destroy` event is part of the scope lifecycle and nothing else, not for DOM elements. As in `scope.on('$destroy', function() {});`

Comment: `angular.element(document.querySelector('#MyDiv')).scope().on('$destroy'`. But maybe you should explain why you have to do this outside of the controller?

Comment: @devqon I am doing this in the controller as soon as it initializes.

Comment: Only `scope` objects have the `on('$destroy')` event. So you can do in your controller: `$scope.$on("destroy", ..)`.

Comment: @devqon unfortunately this is not working either :/

Comment: Sorry it has to be `$scope.$on("$destroy", ..)` of course

Comment: @devqon yep still didn't work out